# present progressive with always that does not imply annoyance?

Tags: present-tense

What is the difference between

I **am always coming** back

I **always come** back

I know that always+present progressive can be used to show annoyance but in this example I don't think it is the case and I know present simple is for regular  actions, habit  that we do every day.

I looked on the web and found that in the first example always means "constantly" and in the second "each" time. Do you agree with this explanation?

I would have thought that I always come back means constantly and "forever true" and am always coming back means that this is a" repeated " action but it has duration and won't last "forever".

Answer (score 1):

Maybe the simplest way to understand this is to just take it as the tenses suggest:

By saying *I am always coming back* you say that you have a *habit* to come back again and again, so it's like a continuous action.

By saying *I always come back* you say that you come back "each time."

Comment: I don't seem to understand clearly the difference: in the first example does it mean that the action can change ,something you have been doing regularly  up to now but could change

Comment: It's like you said in the question: _I looked on the web and found that in the first example always means "constantly" and in the second "each" time. Do you agree with this explanation?_ Yes, I agree. Neither sentence tells anything about a possible change.

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be overstating the use of "always" to show 'annoyance'. Psychologists do say that saying things like "*you always do this*" or "*you never do that*" cause arguments, but that is because the *absolute* nature of these words can only cause the other person to defend themselves. However, there are plenty more situations where "always/never" are perfectly benign.

"*I always come back*" is the correct statement of the two you suggested.

"*I **will** always come back*" is another way of saying it in future continuous.

Comment: I disagree. I can't imagine "I'm always coming back" without an emotional charge - usually annoyance, but possibly a rueful self-deprecation.

Comment: @ColinFine I said almost those exact words to my tearful 5 year old literally last week before I headed out on an errand.  It was calm and reassuring, certainly not annoyed.